# Toshiba laptop keyboard and touchpad locked

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard, touchpad, toshiba-laptop

I apologize if this is not the right place to ask such a question, but this is an emergency since I cannot log in my laptop.

I am using a Toshiba P55W-C5200 Laptop, touch screen, with Windows 10.

After turning it on, the screen got stuck on the welcome page (the one with the screensaver) and the keyboard was not working. I tried typing different keys and got no response.

Oddly the mouse pointer was moving but I could not click (or double-click) on the touchpad.

I used an external keyboard but it is not working. However the usb ports seem to work when I try to charge my phone.

After manually rebooting a couple of times the keyboard just accepted one "enter" key and moved to the password log-in area, but at that point all keys were locked again.

The touch screen does not do anything. It shows a circle when touched (which indicates a click) but the click does not actually happens.

After googling for some time I tried to see if there was a hardware failure with the keyboard connection bus in the motherboard.

I unscrewed the back of the laptop, reconnected the keyboard bus and still nothing.

I tried to remotely access my laptop but the wifi key wont turn on and an ethernet cable will not work either.

Another important point: I cannot enter the BIOS, I keep hitting F12 (and tried some other keys but it goes directly to the Windows screen).

What can I possibly do at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Windows 10 should (theoretically) [enable additional boot options after three failed boot attempts](http://www.howtogeek.com/126016/three-ways-to-access-the-windows-8-boot-options-menu/). Though not the gentlest procedure, try holding down the power switch until the laptop shuts; reboot *and interrupt the reboot with the power switch three more times*. You might then be able to boot using one of the options and try troubleshooting in a Safe mode.
2. Make a USB drive repair boot-up disk such as [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) or [a similar collection](http://alternativeto.net/software/ultimate-boot-cd/). [Go to BIOS to enable booting from the USB drive.](http://www.lostwindowspassword.com/computer-help/how-to-access-enter-bios-on-toshiba-laptop.html)
3. Download a Windows 10 ISO and make a repair disk or USB drive. [Follow instructions for attempting repair.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-perform-a-repair-upgrade-using-the-windows/35160fbe-9352-4e70-9887-f40096ec3085)

Comment: The problem was that I could not enter the BIOS. But your manual interruption was a great idea!! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it helped... I've had to do it on different machines. BTW, perform a disk check afterwards, as this procedure may mess up volume structure.